# Symfony - PHPUnit Prophecy not triggering calls

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I am trying to make the easiest `prophecy` test with Symfony and phpunit.

If I put a BreakPoint in the persist method, I can validate that is pass by it.

```
        $em = $this->prophesize(EntityManagerInterface::class);
        $em->persist(Argument::any())->shouldBeCalledTimes(1);
       

        $realEm = self::$container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $realEm->persist($contract->getSensorConfiguration());
```

But It always says me it's never called.

```
Some predictions failed:
Double\EntityManagerInterface\P1:
  Expected exactly 1 calls that match:
      Double\EntityManagerInterface\P1->persist(*)
    but none were made.
```

I also tried with `createMock` and `expects`

```
        $em = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);
        $em->expects($this->once())->method('persist');
```

but I get the same result...

```
Expectation failed for method name is equal to 'persist' when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you expect $em to be the same as the entitymanager you get from the container. But these are completely different objects.

I do not recommend it but you could first do `self::$container->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager', $em)` (not tested). So now every class that uses this service will use you mock.

Comment: I think I was wrong one the "what i want to achieve". But you are right on the answer, now I get better how prophecy works.